# ¿Cómo agrego este icono al menú dropdown?

Tags: navbar, dropdownlist, font-awesome, menu, icono

Hola tengo el siguiente menu y necesito agregarle un icono de una flecha `<i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>` para indicar que es desplegable, asi como se ve en esta imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no entiendo como hacerlo para que solo aparezca en el primer item

```
<div class="dropdown dd-lang">
        <a class="dropdown__trigger">
          <p class="link-list__link"><strong>English</strong>  </p>
            
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown__menu" style="min-width: 70px;">
            <span class="dropdown__item">
                <a href="/es">
                <p class="link-list__link"><strong>Español</strong>  </p>
                    
                </a>
            </span>
            <span class="dropdown__item">
                <a href="/fr">
                  <p class="link-list__link"><strong>Français</strong> </p>
                    
                </a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: hola, estas usando bootstrap?

Comment: Hola, si es un tema diagramado con liquid

Comment: `<p class="link-list__link"><strong>English</strong><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></p>`

Comment: En mi caso yo usaría el pseudo elemento ::before o ::after. ya lo intentaste?

Comment: No, soy muy nuevo en este tema no conozco mucho

Answer (score 1):

Bueno te voy a explicar como resolver tu duda?

1.. consigue una fuente de iconos de tu agrado, por ejemplo "fontawesome" la  puedes ubicar en google.

2. descarga la fuente a tu computador o copia el enlace cdn.
3. inserta la dirección (local o web) dentro de la etiqueta head

link rel="stylesheet" href="archivodefuente.css" type="text/css"

nota: después de descomprimir el zip busca el archivo all.css en la carpeta css.

4. En tu hoja de css crea un identificador (#list a) o una clase (.list a) y agrégale el pseudo elemento ::after o ::before
5. Define la tipografía a usar para el pseudo elemento con la propiedad font-family y asígnale el valor de 'Font Awesome 5 Free'.
6. Agrega la propiedad content a el identificador o clase y como valor le colocas el id de icono, en tu caso en un chevron-down ".f078" o angle-down ".107"

Comment: Muchas gracias!